# How to share a Powershell psm1 across Azure Functions

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

You can create a `modules` folder and place a `psm1` file there for auto loading. Is there a way to share that `psm1` across functions in the same `App Service`?

Comment: I'm not an expert but as a thought, could you centralise it in blob storage and load it from there from within your functions?

Comment: sorry, but how about some examples. You seem to come from a long way

Comment: @MickyBalladelli Can you say a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you may move your modules folder up the directory tree and place it under **wwwroot**, e.g. **D:\home\site\wwwroot\mymodules**.  Auto-loading will not occur in this setup, so you will need to explicitly add the Import-Module command in your PowerShell script, e.g.

```
Import-Module "D:\home\site\wwwroot\mymodules\MyScript.psm1";
```

If you suspect that `MyScript.psm1` is already installed on the system and need to override it with your version, add the -Global flag as follows

```
Import-Module "D:\home\site\wwwroot\mymodules\MyScript.psm1" -Global;
```